# How to tell which field failed Gson serialization

Tags: java, android, serialization, reflection, gson

I am serializing some rather complex objects using `new Gson().fromJson(String, Class<?>)` and even though all my properties look OK, I still get this stack trace:

```
06-09 10:10:58.768: E/AndroidRuntime(27775): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 10:10:58.768: E/AndroidRuntime(27775): Process: com.my.project, PID: 27775
06-09 10:10:58.768: E/AndroidRuntime(27775): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid value for field
06-09 10:10:58.768: E/AndroidRuntime(27775):    at java.lang.reflect.Field.setField(Native Method)
06-09 10:10:58.768: E/AndroidRuntime(27775):    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:585)
06-09 10:10:58.768: E/AndroidRuntime(27775):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:95)
06-09 10:10:58.768: E/AndroidRuntime(27775):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
06-09 10:10:58.768: E/AndroidRuntime(27775):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
06-09 10:10:58.768: E/AndroidRuntime(27775):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
06-09 10:10:58.768: E/AndroidRuntime(27775):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
06-09 10:10:58.768: E/AndroidRuntime(27775):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
... more
```

Is there any way to have Gson tell me the field name it's failing on?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I find is, in debug mode, try the same operation removing one field per time...
Is not a good answer, but I cannot find a better way.